# Prove that the induced map of g o f, where g and f are homotopy inverses, is equivalent to the change of basepoint homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have this problem as follows:

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ are homotopy inverses, the homotopy $gf \sim id_{X}$ gives a path $\gamma$ in X from $gf(x_0)$ to $x_0$. Prove that the induced homomorphism $g_{\ast}f_{\ast}$ is equal to the change-of-basepoint isomorphism $\beta_{\gamma}$.

So I know that inducing a homomorphism of the map $gf: X \rightarrow X$ gives us $g_{\ast}f_{\ast}: \pi_{1}(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(X, gf(x_0))$. We know that $gf(x_0)$ is a point in X, and since $gf$ and $id_X$ are homotopic, we have a path $\gamma$ from $x_0$ to $gf(x_0)$. Don't these two facts alone make $g_{\ast}f_{\ast}$ a change of basepoint isomorphism? I know the change of basepoint map $\beta_{\gamma}$ is defined by sending a class of loops $f$ to $\bar{h}fh$. In this situation, is $\gamma$ our path? And $g_{\ast}f_{\ast}$ is an isomorphism since $g$ and $f$ are homotopy inverses? In short, I'm just not sure where to go from here, or how to formalize everything I just said.